# How to copy docker containers to a new host, including stored data?

Tags: docker

I have done some developing with docker containers for InfluxDB, Chronograf and Grafana (using [this docker-compose setup](https://github.com/vamseekm/docker-influxdb-grafana-chronograf)) on my local machine::

```
version: "3"

services:

    influxdb:
        image: influxdb:1.5
        volumes:
            - influxdb_data:/var/lib/influxdb
        ports:
            - 127.0.0.1:8086:8086
        restart: always
    chronograf:
        image: chronograf:1.5
        volumes:
            - chronograf_data:/var/lib/chronograf
        ports:
            - 127.0.0.1:8087:8888
        restart: always
    grafana:
        image: grafana/grafana
        ports:
            - 127.0.0.1:3000:3000
        volumes:
            - grafana_data:/var/lib/grafana
        restart: always

volumes:
    influxdb_data:
    chronograf_data:
    grafana_data:
```

I want to copy these containers to a cloud based VM, including data that is stored in InfluxDB, and dashboards created in Grafana.

What is the preferred way to do this?

Things I have tried:

- Save and Load: this only includes the docker images, so no data is loaded on the new host.
- Export and Import: somehow when I try to import a docker container, it shows no error, but I can't start the container as it doesn't show up in my list of containers, nor my list of images.

Comment: #2: May sound like a dumb question but can't hurt to ask; after you imported the data, did you re-run your compose file to fetch the image(s) and create the container(s)?

Comment: @J.ScottElblein I only tried it with a single container

Comment: After doing the restore, go ahead and do `docker-compose up -d` again to re-pull the images and re-start the containers. See if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I need to move containers here's all I do; I just backup any named volumes I need, and then restore them to the new host (I manually create the new named volume on the host first and import to it there).

Aside from that there's not much more to containers; the rest gets fetched when you re-deploy your compose file (or do `docker run`).

```
# Backup
docker run --rm -v volume_name:/volume -v c:\migrate:/backup alpine tar -cjf /backup/backup.tar.bz2 -C /volume ./
```

```
# Restore
docker run --rm -v volume_name:/volume -v c:\migrate:/backup alpine tar -C /volume/ -xjf /backup/backup.tar.bz2
```

In my compose file I set those volumes as external so docker knows not to try to create them, and use the existing one(s):

i.e. if I created a named volume "my_bitwarden_data" then I'd use:

```
volumes:
  my_bitwarden_data:
    external: true
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the paths you mention should refer to. I guess the -v are volume names in their format. Is /backup/backup.tar.bz2 the target destination? And what is /volume ./?

Comment: All you really need to do is change `volume_name` to the volume you are backing up, and `backup.tar.bz2` to whatever name you want (i.e. `bitwarden-backup.tar.bz2`) if you're doing more than one, just to make the filename more identifiable. Give it a try, it won't hurt anything; you'll see what it does.